# +/- sign for number prefix: lexical / syntactical element?

Tags: syntax, numbers, token, sign

I would like to add +/- sign support to number for my expression evaluator, however I'm not sure whether it should be lexical element as part of number token (e.g. `number = [\+\-]*[0-9]+`) or syntactical (e.g. `primary ::= [ ( "+" | "-" ) ] primary | number` where `number = [0-9]+`).

As can be seen from above, this sign could be arbitrarily many. Currently, I've implemented the syntactical version using both recursive descent and operator precedence parsing. But I'm still not sure whether this is a good choice or not. One thing I spot, the syntactical version requires recursion for each sign it meets.

Comment: Why would you allow arbitrarily many?  Something like `primary ::= [ ( "+" | "-") ] number | number` would seem better.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it's kinda useless, too. A language should be expressive enough to ease writing, but not overly expressive that almost anything would be acceptable. Anyway, many programming languages that allow this, so I thought maybe I should implement it as well. I'll take that simple optional single sign approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good if you use both: `1 - -1 = 2`

Comment: I think duedl0r means both binary minus (not shown in your grammer) and unary minus (which you've shown).   I don't think this is an answer to your question, but it hints at the answer.

Comment: Oh, I already have that. Both are working fine, I just doubt the approach's efficiency

Comment: Efficiency? Unless you are parsing millions of expressions per second, I wouldn't worry much about the impact of this choice on efficiency.  The claim is that if you choose wrong, you can't make the parser work.

Answer (score 0):

As a practical matter, it is hard to make "-" be a lexical element, because you also need to recognize it in its other usage as the standard two-operand "subtract" operator.

If you produce "-" as a standalone lexeme, the parser can easily decide if it is the subtract operator or a negate operator because of the grammmar rules you provide.

The lexer cannot make this decision since by design it doesn't have access to the parser state.  So how can it reasonably tell if the "-" character it has just encountered, should cause the generation of a '-' token, or be consumed by a following numeric literal?  If it is consumed by the following numeric literal, then your parser will have trouble with the expression:

```
 x - -2
```

What you probabaly want as grammar rules to handle both type of minus signs are:

```
expression = sum ;

sum =  term ;
sum = sum '+' term ;
sum = sum '-' term ;

term = primary ;
term = term '*' primary ;
term = term '/' primary

primary = '-' primary ;
primary = '(' expression ')' ;
primary = number ;
primary = identifier ;
```

(I'll let you refactor these into whatever form suits you).

Comment: I already have the complete grammar, I only doubt the primary expression which I posted above. My grammar is left-recursion free anyway :)